# run a single program on raspberry pi 3 with no user interface

Tags: controller, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

The goal is to interface with and control two pieces of equipment (receiving and logging data). I don't need the gui...or likely much of anything that could cause the system to crash. There is no chance that a human can interact with the system once it goes to where it is going.

The system will be turned on and automatically run...is this possible...and do I even need a full OS for this to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Of course this is possible, just google for "raspberry pi headless". There is a similar question here: [raspberrypi.stackexchange.com](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/28768/run-two-python-script-automatically-on-headless-raspberry-pi-project)

Comment: You are much appreciated.